# How to sort desc/asc in full text search index of couchbase

Tags: java, couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I have this query to execute from my application against a full text search couchbase index :

```
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = buildQuery(params);
SearchQuery searchQuery = new SearchQuery(
                "index_name",
                booleanQuery
).sort("createionDateTime")
 .limit(10);
```

How to specify sort direction for createionDateTime ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

sort direction is defined using "-" for descending and nothing for ascending direction
so for this case, to chse desc direction

```
sort("-createionDateTime")
```